# Are there any publicly available Serpent s-boxes of a non-linear order 3, optimized for x86_64?

Tags: s-boxes, serpent

The [original serpent paper](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~rja14/Papers/serpent.pdf) claims that the s-boxes provided are of non-linear order 3, the maximum. However, this [has turned out to be false](https://eprint.iacr.org/2009/038.pdf), as some of them are of order 2.

Are there any s-boxes available for serpent that comply with the properties indicated in the paper, and ideally, optimized for x86_64 architecture ?

If not, how could one find strong s-boxes that both respect those properties and are resistant to known attacks against serpent ?

Comment: Do you mean nonlinear order by algebraic order?

Comment: Serpent's S-boxes are only 4-bit, and there is quite a bit of research on ideal 4-bit S-boxes.

Comment: This paper (https://eprint.iacr.org/2011/218.pdf ) contains a table of 4 bit sboxes used for different ciphers. for better implementation , i suggest to run the source code in this paper (https://tosc.iacr.org/index.php/ToSC/article/view/7406/6578) to find optimal implementation.